# Can html2canvas render svg in a page?

Tags: svg, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to create a 'screenshot' of a HTML page that contains SVG.
Everything looks good, except the  element.
I know that it should be possible to render SVG in Canvas; PhantomJS, fabric.js and CanVG do it.

Is this something that html2canvas does not support? Or am I doing something wrong, and this should just work?

If this has not been implemented, what is the best way to extend html2canvas (using canvg)?

Comment: I found my answer (or, Google did): [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Capturing SVG images works by transforming them into canvas, using [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg). Include both javascript files as indicated on that page. Then the easiest way to do this is:

```
<body onload="canvg()">
```

See the [parameterless call example](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/examples/convert.htm).
When all SVG images have been converted, html2canvas works flawlessly.

Of course, all SVG images will be converted to canvases, but I did not see a difference.