# html and Svg to Canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html2canvas

```
<div id="Contents">
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
<svg></svg>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
<svg></svg>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my html code. I want to convert it canvas image.

```
html2canvas($("#Contents"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
   window.open(canvas.toDataURL());

  }
});
```

I use html2canvas plugin for convert it to image but It does not show svg. 
I solve converting svg tp canvas but now html2canvas not working

```
  var $to=$("#MainContents").clone();

            $($to).children(".box").each(function() {
    var svg = ResizeArray[$(this).children(".box-content").children().attr("new-id")-1].svg();
            var Thiscanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            Thiscanvas.setAttribute("style", "height:" + 100 + "px;width:" + 100+ "px;");

            canvg(Thiscanvas, svg);

            $(this).append(Thiscanvas);

        });
        html2canvas($($to), {
      onrendered: function(canvasq) {
        var w=window.open(canvasq.toDataURL());
        w.print();
      }
    });
```

I can convert svg to canvas but html2canvas function not working.

Comment: [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) can render SVG on canvas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165426/can-html2canvas-render-svg-in-a-page

Answer (score 9):

You will need to use canvg library for drawing this svg to a temporary canvas and then remove that canvas once you take the screenshot using html2canvas.

Here is the link for canvg : https://github.com/canvg/canvg

Try this:

```
//find all svg elements in $container
//$container is the jQuery object of the div that you need to convert to image. This div may contain highcharts along with other child divs, etc
var svgElements= $container.find('svg');

//replace all svgs with a temp canvas
svgElements.each(function () {
    var canvas, xml;

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";
    //convert SVG into a XML string
    xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);

    // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
    xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');

    //draw the SVG onto a canvas
    canvg(canvas, xml);
    $(canvas).insertAfter(this);
    //hide the SVG element
    this.className = "tempHide";
    $(this).hide();
});

//...
//HERE GOES YOUR CODE FOR HTML2CANVAS SCREENSHOT
//...

//After your image is generated revert the temporary changes
$container.find('.screenShotTempCanvas').remove();
$container.find('.tempHide').show().removeClass('tempHide');
```

Answer (score 3):

As the html2canvas don't take svg elements, you need to convert all svg elements to canvas before you call the html2canvas method. You could use the [**canvg**](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) library to convert all the svg to canvas. You can pass the jquery object(which needs to convert from svg to canvas, can also be a parent element) to the following method:

```
function svgToCanvas (targetElem) {
var nodesToRecover = [];
var nodesToRemove = [];

var svgElem = targetElem.find('svg');

svgElem.each(function(index, node) {
    var parentNode = node.parentNode;
    var svg = parentNode.innerHTML;

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvg(canvas, svg);

    nodesToRecover.push({
        parent: parentNode,
        child: node
    });
    parentNode.removeChild(node);

    nodesToRemove.push({
        parent: parentNode,
        child: canvas
    });

    parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
});

html2canvas(targetElem, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The snippet worked like a charm. I'm finally able to get it working. However, I still have to calibrate it as I'm noticing the snapshots cropping the charts in a weird way.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works beautifully. Since I am not using jQuery in my application, I had to change couple of lines in svgCanvas for getting the svg elements and iterating through them.  The rest of the functions worked without any changes. My code is...

```
function svgToCanvas (targetElem) {
        var nodesToRecover = [];
        var nodesToRemove = [];

        var svgElems = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");

        for (var i=0; i<svgElems.length; i++) {
            var node = svgElems[i];
            var parentNode = node.parentNode;
            var svg = parentNode.innerHTML;

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

            canvg(canvas, svg);

            nodesToRecover.push({
                parent: parentNode,
                child: node
            });
            parentNode.removeChild(node);

            nodesToRemove.push({
                parent: parentNode,
                child: canvas
            });

            parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code has quite some unused variables. I know it's old but you should probably look into it :-)

Answer (score -1):

html2canvas doesn't allow to save SVG is an issue.
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95

If you want to save an SVG you an follow other way, like to transform your SVG into a PNG for example

SVG -> canvas -> PNG -> canvas -> PNG

Comment: Can I use html2canvas with canvg ? . I am gonna convert first canvg before use html2canvas. I think they are not work together.

Comment: you can try it, see in the link that I have posted into my answer someone have tried already this

Answer (score -2):

You can create your own innerHTML, like the following [setSVG](https://github.com/yelloxing/image2D/blob/dev/src/core/polyfill.js)：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkYGJ.png)

In fact, you only need to pay attention to two steps: creating the SVG context label and setting properties (with context)

createElementNS and setAttributeNS are two methods you may need！

Common namespaces are as follows:

- svg:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
- xhtml:http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
- xlink:http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
- xml:http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
- xmlns:http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have revised the answer