# Convert all the content of a DIV into a SVG thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a webapp where I have various slides in different divs.
In the left screen I have a list of all those slides as mini-thumbnails.

Is there a way to convert every slide div into SVG thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

You can use html2canvas to achieve what you want.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

For a similar question, please refer to: [Can html2canvas render svg in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165426/can-html2canvas-render-svg-in-a-page)

Comment: I'm using html2canvas, but it doesn't work well with CSS-Transform properties such as rotate(), scale(), translate3D() (I'm using Impress.js).  That's why I'm asking for another library to create thumbnails but not html2canvas

Comment: @edwardoyarzun I actually haven't found any other libraries besides html2canvas. :/

Comment: OK, I think my solution will be, clone the DIV node using cloneNode() and the append it to the thumbnail container div, and then scale it with CSS Transform.

Comment: I had a similar solution as @Eduardo: render the DIV in iframe and transform the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If these slides are described by svg element, you can use "use" element like this.

```
<!--main slide-->
<div>
    <svg id="slide_1"></svg>
</div>
...
<!--thumbnail-->
<div>
    <svg><use xlink:href="#slide_1"/></svg>
    ...
</div>
```